# Office JS - Italic between quotation marks

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office365, office-js

Beginer here.

My problem might be basic but I am struggling to find a way to solve it.

I'm developing a Word add-in using the Office JS API (in Script Lab). I want a function that will put any text between quotation marks in italics, but I don't want the quotation marks themselves in italics.

I know how to find text between quotation marks, but I don't know how to exclude the quotation marks from my range. I tried unsuccessfully using the slice method.

Do you have any idea how to achieve this?

```
const body = context.document.body;
const searchResultsQuotationMarks = body.search(String.fromCharCode(0x00ab) + "*" + String.fromCharCode(0x00bb), {
      matchWildcards: true
    });

searchResultsQuotationMarks.load("text, font");
await context.sync();

searchResultsQuotationMarks.items.forEach((resultQuotationMarks) => {

    // Not working
    const text = resultQuotationMarks.text.slice(1, -1);

    const font = resultQuotationMarks.font;
    font.italic = true;
    });

    await context.sync();
  });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: FWIW I doon't think sliceing will help because it doesn't change the Range. There is no simple equivlent to VBA Range.MoveStart etc. (there was a short conversation about the lack of an Office-JS equivalent. But you *may* be able to do something like this: for each found text, get the length of the found text, say it's 8, then do a .search on [!«]{6}, and italicize the resulting range. My own attempts have failed so far but perhaps you or someone else can work that out.

Comment: Failing that, another thing that might work (I haven't tried) is to get the range.rangeLocation(start) and range.rangeLocation(end), record whether they are italicized or not, italicize the entire found range, then restore the previous state for the start and end. Horrible, but perhaps workable. FWIW I tried to edit your question to include the office-js tag as you'll probably get better feedback, but there was a problem.

Comment: Hi Jonsson, Thanks a lot. I'll try that and let you know.

Comment: I finally found a solution by doing a second search of any character but a braket inside the first range I found. Not very efficient but it works.